# Ionic framework and Cordova Geolocation speed return NAN

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, geolocation, cordova-plugins, nan

I’m trying to create an app using the Ionic Framework and the Cordova Geolocation plugin. I want to show the GPS speed on the screen but it always returns NAN. Other values like latitude and longitude can be displayed on the screen, but not the speed. I have no idea why this doesn’t work, any help would be very much appreciated!

here’s a print screen: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hmq5eryo60mvc95/Capture.JPG?dl=0

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ionic','ngCordova'])

.controller('DashboardController', function($scope, $cordovaGeolocation) {

  // get the gps stuff
  var posOptions = {timeout: 10000, enableHighAccuracy: true};
  $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition(posOptions)
      .then(function (position) {

      // change this to speed...
      GPSspeed = position.coords.speed;

      // this will refresh the scope variables every second
      setInterval(function(){ 
        // start the clock
        clock();
        $scope.activeTime = timer;
        $scope.speed = GPSspeed;

        // refresh the scope in the view
        $scope.$apply();
      }, 1000);

     }, function(err) {
      console.log(err)
     });
});
```

Comment: I got it to work!

during the developement, the webbrowser is able to provide the latitude and longitude information. However speed and heading is not supported by any browser. The weird thing was that the speed on my phone also returned NAN. But once I tested it while moving it suddenly started displaying the speed!

Comment: Checked the same code. But getting speed `null`